# How do you filter pages on power bi?

Tags: powerbi, filtering

Make use of filters that can be applied across pages and visuals, THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TO APPLY ON THE PROJECT I HAVE]

I tried applying the filtering on one page of the report and it worked but thats not really how i have to do it. i have to filter one page for all the other pages.

Comment: Please be more specific as there are a number of things you maybe referring to. Slicers or Filters?